# How to generate database script codes under VS2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

In Sql Server 2008 when I right click on a database there is a menu in `Tasks->Generate Scripts` that would give the hole database script codes.Now is there a service like this in VS2012's server explorer that give me hole database scripts codes?

Comment: did you see this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2xsa6y.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no native way of doing that from VS2012.

Comment: Did you see this, i can't use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2xsa6y.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible Generate script from all db object like sql server managment, but in SQL Server Object Explorer you can generate script from each table by:

Select own db in **sql serever object explorer** ->right click and select **script as -> Create To -> Clipboard**